# ASP.net MVC - Why each element on a different row?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm creating a simple ASP.net MVC form using bootstrap. My form looks like:

```
@using(Html.BeginForm()){
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">@Html.TextBox("City", "", new { placeholder = "City" })</div>
        <div class="col-md-4">@Html.TextBox("State", "", new { placeholder = "State", maxlength = "2" })</div>
        <div class="col-md-4">@Html.TextBox("Zip", "", new { placeholder = "Zip Code" })</div>
    </div>
}
```

Although I'm using appropriate classes for columns and textboxes should be inline, they are appearing in different rows. To my understanding, as long as the column widths are within a limit of 12 columns, inline elements should appear in the same row. Why is there a line break between these elements?

N.B: If I remove divs for individual columns and put all textboxes in a single div, they appear in the same row correctly.

Answer (score 1):

> To my understanding, as long as the column widths are within a limit
>   of 12 columns, inline elements should appear in the same row.

Cut off for **col-md-x** is 970px. It means if the browser size is less than 970px, they will be rendered as individual row. You can read [here](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options).

If you ***always*** want them to appear them in a single row, you want to use **col-xs-x**, or mix classes like this -

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12"></div>
   <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12"></div>
   <div class="col-sm-4 col-xs-12"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've mixed classes like <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">, but they still appear on separate rows, not together in a single row. Browser size is definitely >750px, actually I'm testing it on 1368px resolution.

Comment: It is not about resolution instead browser size. For **col-md-x** to work, browser size should be greater than 970px. If you still have an issue, could you upload your code to [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 0):

If you want your textboxes inline, they should be put inside a single div tag. but if you want to put it in different divs, you can try to remove "col-md-4" in your divs and use css instead, like this:

```
.row {
   display: flex;
}
```

Also, add some extra "padding" or "margin" property for spacing between those textboxes.

If there is anything wrong about my answer, please feel free to correct it. Thanks!